# Does Windows Phone allow developer to build ad hoc connection in Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, adhoc

I just started to build an App for Windows Phone 7 and I want to know if the WP7 support the ad hoc connection for app since I want to use the ad hoc connection to do something for my app. Actually I searched the library and I don't get anything useful related to this issue.

Actually what I want to do is to connect two phones via the ad hoc network. My app initiates the ad hoc network wait for other phone running the same app to join the network and communicate

Comment: You'll get more useful responses if you include more detail in your question. What are you trying to connect to? Another app? A database? A web service? "Ad hoc connection" isn't a term that's used in Windows Phone development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. WP7 does not allow you to create an adhoc network through the public APIs.

If you have 2 devices on the same wireless netowrk you can create a UDP conenction between the two though.